# Virtual box couldn't be installed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I tried to install virtual box using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt

But this gave me the following errors
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-qt : Depends: virtualbox (= 4.3.10-dfsg-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed.

Try installing the below packages!

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then run the below command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I solved the problem by removing -qt- which means that:

```
sudo apt-get instal virtualbox
```

Comment: That's the backend package, have you tried loading `virtualbox-qt` now and seen what happens?